# Firestore Rules: Insecure rule notification for creating a user because of the (recommended) single check on request.auth.uid

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to set security rules in my DB's users documents. In particular, for the creation of a user.

[According to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions), you can write:

```
match /users/{user} {
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
                            //  && other booleans to validate data
```

But, [according to the documentation again](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#access_for_any_authenticated_user), writing only `request.auth.uid != null` without any other boolean concerning this value nore a role, makes this rule "insecure". Indeed:

> When you're checking for authentication, you might also want to use one of the authentication properties to further restrict access to specific users for specific data sets. Learn more about adding security conditions and role-based access.

Of course, in the case of the creation of a user, it doesn't seem possible.

However, Firestore Security Rules will send me the notification that there is at least one insecure rule: this one.

How can I deal with this "problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved and your firestore rule can be enhanced at the same time.

Just add a condition to check if the `currentUser` who is adding the  `newUser` already exists in the `users` collection.

You can further enhance the same by checking if the `currentUser` has the necessary privileges to add a new `user` if you want to only allow a particular set of privileged users to create new users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it would look like that: ` allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)); ` ? Is `request.auth.uid != null` required in this case?

Comment: "You can further enhance the same by checking if the currentUser has the necessary privileges to add a new user"   ===>   The user creates its own account, not another user.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler The `auth` is actually a variable which contains information about authenticated user (or is `null`, if the user is not authenticated). So the first check is required so that you can restrict create to authenticated users. If it is removed, it will result in a `null reference error` . I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler In the case of the `currentUser` adding his own account, the enhancement can be omitted. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Dennis: if this `null reference error` is raised, the query will be denied. So the `exists` call might be not written, no?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Yes and an error like "Missing or Insufficient Permissions" will be thrown.